# MongoDB increment at arbitrary array position

Tags: arrays, mongodb, increment

I want to use an array as a counter for documents that are associated with this document. Each array element corresponds to a document, and the number in that array corresponds to some piece of data about that document. These numbers are not stored with their associated documents so queries can be performed on the fields of the 'primary' document as well as the data in the array for the 'associated' documents.

Due to the vagaries of $inc and array initialization, there appears to be no way to do this:

```
> use foo
switched to db foo
> db.foo.save({id: []})
> db.foo.update({}, {$inc: {'id.4': 1}})
> db.foo.find().pretty()
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5279b3339a056b26e64eef0d"),
    "id" : [
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        1
    ]
}
> db.foo.update({}, {$inc: {'id.2': 1}})
Cannot apply $inc modifier to non-number
```

Is there some way to increment a null or initialize the array with zeros?

An alternative is storing the array values in a key/value format which would therefore be a sparse array, but there's no way to upsert into an array, which makes that alternative infeasible.

Comment: do you know what size your array is going to be?

Comment: Unfortunately no. It can expand theoretically indefinitely, although practically it's probably limited to 1000 or so, the distribution will be strongly skewed towards 1, and the current average is ~3. That's only 4kB per object to pre-initialize, but there may be millions or billions of these objects so it starts to add up.

Comment: if you think they can grow infinitely, it's not a good idea to put them in one array - your document size will keep growing which is bad for performance.  Meanwhile, there is a trick you can use as is.  {$inc:{'id.0':0, 'id.1':0, 'id.2':0, 'id.3':1}} will generate an array id:[0,0,0,1] if it wasn't there and will increment 4th element if it was. $inc by 0 is a no-op, but will do the right thing for you with id:[ ]

Comment: Re performance, this is true, but I expect that the arrays in 99.9% of cases won't be particularly big. I can't imagine ever actually exceeding 1000 for the use case unless someone is abusing the system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While I'm not in favor of potentially unlimited in size arrays, there is a trick you can use to make the right thing happen here:

```
db.foo.insert({id:[]})
```

Whenever you increment a counter at index N, make sure you increment by 0 all indexes up to N.

```
db.foo.update({}, {$inc: {'id.0':0, 'id.1':0, 'id.2':0, 'id.3':0, 'id.4':1 } })
db.foo.update({}, {$inc: {'id.0':0, 'id.1':0, 'id.2':1 } })
db.foo.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5279c8de0e05b308d0cf21ca"), "id" : [  0,  0,  1,  0,  1 ] }
```

Comment: Tricksy, I like it. However, it turned out that I could just $push a zero onto the array every time I created an 'associated' document without incurring an extra DB write and that did the trick as well. Should've thought of it earlier.

Comment: I'm a fan to tricky yet straight-foward solutions - this one has the advantage of growing array N elements at a time...

Comment: Does that make a significant performance difference if I'm already writing to a several doc fields anyway? In my solution, I $push onto the array in the primary document every time I create a new associated document, along with other writes to the primary document. In your scheme, I only create the array entries as needed, but potentially could do many more no-op increments than are necessary. I don't know enough about mongoguts to say which is better, performance-wise.

Comment: nice thing about no-ops is they are ... no-ops :)  they should be next to free.  Now adding new fields will grow the document so occasionally will slow things down as more space needs to be allocated for it.  Consider usePowersOf2 sizes for this collection to minimize impact of that...